# Given a set of arrays, find out which arrays are subset of another

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, set, subset

I am working on a project, where we have a set of arrays with same (and fixed) length, and their entries could be Null or a number. Some arrays are "somehow" subsets of other arrays. In this problem, we define subset in another way:

Array "x" is a subset of array "y" iff for each index i in x, x[i] ≠ Null => x[i] = y[i]

For example, array [2, Null, 1, Null] is a subset of [2, 5, 1, 8]

But array [3, 2, Null, Null] isn't a subset of [3, 1, Null, Null] or [3, Null, Null, Null].

I want to find for each array whether it is a subset of another array (and if it is, find its index). It doesn't have to be the optimum answer, it is sufficient to find a maximal one.

At the moment, I implemented an algorithm with O(N^2) which has two nested loops, and for each array "a", I check it with all arrays such as "b" which is not a subset of any other array, if "a" is a subset of "b". (And the subset checking process requires iteration on all indices of arrays which is O(Length of arrays). ) So The whole algorithm is O(N^2 * Length of arrays).

I have an idea that we could add the arrays one by one, and check if the new array is a subset of arrays added until that moment, and if it didn't have a superset, we add it to our list.

Also, we can add our arrays in a trie which the first-level groups them by their first index (those which are Null, 0, 1, etc), the second level groups each first-level group by their second index, and so on. When we want to find out one array (x)'s subsets, we check its first index. If it wasn't Null, we check the group that their first index is equal to x[1]. But if x[1] = Null, we have to check all groups at this level. And we go on with this BFS-like algorithm. But I'm not sure if this algorithm works efficiently in worst-case or average-case.

Would you please recommend me some efficient algorithms for solving this problem?

Comment: to check every array from a list of array [O(n)] [whether it is a subset of another or not], you need to take i-th array and you have to check every element of it [O(n)], since i think it is not possible to do without [O(n^2)] !!

Comment: "It doesn't have to be the optimum answer, it is sufficient to find a maximal one." Can you define what is maximal one?

Comment: @SomeDude For example, suppose that we 3 arrays, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, Null], [1, Null, Null]. if we add from first to last, the two last arrays are a subset of the first array and are not added to the array set. 
But if we add in reverse order, all three arrays are added to the set.
Here I mean we need to find a good number of these subset relations.

Comment: Are all arrays of equal lenght?

Comment: @EdenHazard : "Here I mean we need to find a good number of these subset relations" - do you mean you need an answer of 3 instead of 1 when you add all three arrays? Please update your question with clear inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: @Aldert Yes. Their lengths are equal and fixed.

Comment: @SomeDude I have a data structure that can find data of subset arrays from their superset. So I only need to store the supersets in the data structure. In that example, when arrays are added one by one, the result could be 3, and nothing much could be done. But on average, adding one by one will result in a good number of relations. So I don't care about getting the best order.